# Rails - Need help setting up loosely coupled associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have the following models, with their relevant associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :ratings
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :ratings
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Given a specific `Rating`, I need to get to the corresponding `Review` (if a review exists).

I need to keep `ratings` and `reviews` loosely coupled.  (I do not want to set up my model so that a `Review` `belongs_to` a `Rating`)

How should I set up a `rating's` association to `reviews`?

Once I'm working with a specific rating in a view, I can call `@rating.product.reviews.where(:user_id => @rating.user.id).first`, but I'd like it to be cleaner/more efficient if possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using :conditions like so:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews,
           :through => :user,
           :source => :reviews,
           :conditions => ['#{Review.table_name}.product_id = #{product_id}']
end
```

If that doesn't work, do this instead (very much like what @RobinBrouwer answer):

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  def reviews
    user.reviews.where(:product => product)
  end
end
```

Comment: He doesn't need to specify the user twice - `user.reviews.where(:product => product)` will suffice.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here:  "{:product_id => &:product_id}"  ?   Thx.

Comment: Thanks.  This works (except you don't need the :source option).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `has_many :through` relation to get all the reviews.

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :product_reviews, :through => :product, :source => :reviews
end
```

You can now do the following to do the same as you did above:

```
@rating.product_reviews.where(:user_id => @rating.user.id).first
```

Not really a great improvement. You can put it inside an instance method to clean things up:

```
def review
  product_reviews.where(:user_id => user_id).first
end
```

Now you can simply do the following to get the same result:

```
@rating.review
```

That's it.